# Dynamically create .gitmodules and clone/pull all repos with one command

Tags: git

I'd like to use git submodule features to dynamically create a repo made up of several other repos. The reasoning would make this question a lot more complicated but basically I want to dynamically create a `.gitmodules` on the fly and run one command to clone all the submodules.

Ideally the workflow would be:

1. `git init`
2. Copy in a `.gitmodules` file
3. Run `git submodule [?]` to clone and place everything defined in `.gitmodules` at once

The only way I'm seeing to clone repos on a freshly initialized git repo however is to use `git submodule add` on each repo.

Is there a way to make this work without running `git submodule add` on each repo?

Note: It is important that my workflow starts from a freshly initialize git repo. I do not want to clone the top level repo that has been configured already..

Comment: Is the reason because you're trying to manage dependencies with Git?

Comment: I'd like to use git to build the directory structure required to run the app for local development. The front-end repo differs depending on other factors so I need to be able to dynamically define what they should be and build the file system. I'd like to use submodule commands to pull updates as a set as well. Just trying to avoid writing this from scratch if it's something I can stand on git to do.

Comment: You can write a script to do that, but you would be reinventing existing tools. Git makes a poor build tool, configuration manager, or dependency manager. I would recommend 1) packaging your dependencies and using a dependency manager (many will pull from Git), 2) writing an installer, possibly using a build tool, and 3) handle dynamic definitions with configuration. Exactly what to use depends on your language, framework, and circumstance. I'd recommend asking that more complicated question.